# how to take something from another class in python?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I made two different classes `Oranges` and `Witches` and one more `MyGame` in my draw function in `MyGame` class I need to take position from the `Oranges` class and add it to the position in my `Witches` class. for example the new position of the witch = position of the orange - position of the witch. How can I do this?

```
class Orange(object):
    def __init__(self, position, image):
        self.image = image
        self.position = (random.randint(350, 500), random.randint(250, 350))  

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, self.position)

class Witch(object):
    def __init__(self, position, image):
        self.image = image
        self.position = (random.randint(0, 760), random.randint(0, 0))
        self.position1 = (random.randint(0, 0), random.randint(0, 520))
        self.position2  = (random.randint (0, 760), random.randint(480, 520))
        self.position3 = (random.randint (730, 760), random.randint(0, 520))

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, self.position)

class MyGame(object):
    def draw(self):
```

Comment: new_orange=Orange(...input parameters...),
    new_witch=Witch(...input parameters...)
    new_witch.position=new_orange.position-new_witch.position....What is the problem in doing this?

Comment: Doublecheck your indentation. You probably posted from a text editor set to use tabs for indentation, which is usually not a great choice for SO code samples. (Unfortunately this being Python correcting it for you would involve making a guess.)

Comment: Also: it's recommended to simplify code samples to include only what's relevant to your problem. Here all the drawing code etc is mostly clutter.

Comment: @millimoose: I wholeheartedly agree with you. Posting such a long code will delay the answering process. It is always wise to dissect the question and just ask what is needed rather than to provide too much detail which is generally annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is really long but just to subtract the position of the orange and that of witch class, following should suffice. You have to create an object for orange as well as witch class and just do the following. I don't know if you are asking some other things but from your question, this is all I can tell.

```
new_orange=Orange(...input parameters...)
new_witch=Witch(...input parameters...)
new_witch.position=new_orange.position-new_witch.position
```

Note: The two positions you have is tuple, so I recommend you look into map feature and do something like this:

```
new_witch.position=tuple(map(lambda x,y:x-y,new_orange.position,new_witch.position))
```

This will give you the iterable object and you can convert it to tuple which I want to leave it for you as a motivation to go and look for lambda and iterable objects.

Comment: well he has to do a little more than that ... but conceptually yeah (+1)

Comment: I don't know how it can be answered when the code is so long and question is so vague. He shows some effort for sure but might be confused about what he really wants. I made my way in programming like this as a hobbyist and feel the pain but at the meantime, the code is too much and question is too small. Don't know what he truly wants apart from """the new position of the witch = position of the orange - position of the witch"""

Comment: their tuples ... so subtracting them raw like that will blow up but hopefully he can figure out what he needs to do

Comment: Take a look at the updated answer and please visit and look about map, lambda and iterables. It will help you.